# Discord.js not letting me change prefix

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to change the prefix for my bot but when I try to change the prefix constant, I get an error saying "unexpected token".
Working code:

```
const prefix = '!'
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if(msg.content[0] !== prefix) {
        return
    }
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
const prefix = 'b?'
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if(msg.content[0] b?== prefix) {
        return
    }
```

The error I get:

```
 C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\parser\index.js:93
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: G:\Code\Discord Bot\index.js: Unexpected token, expected ")" (12:22)

  10 | const prefix = 'b?'
  11 | bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
> 12 |     if(msg.content[0] b?== prefix) {
     |                       ^
  13 |         return
  14 |     }
  15 |
    at Parser._raise (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:788:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:781:17)
    at Parser.raise (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:742:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3250:16)
    at Parser.expect (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3224:28)
    at Parser.parseHeaderExpression (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12940:10)
    at Parser.parseIfStatement (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13032:22)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12715:21)
    at Parser.parseStatement (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12670:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\Me\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13259:25) {
  loc: Position { line: 12, column: 22 },
  pos: 352,
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
  reasonCode: 'UnexpectedToken'
}
[Finished in 0.984s]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's not how the code works.
What you're trying to achieve is in the code below

```
const prefix = 'b?'
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if(msg.content == b?prefix) {
        return
    }
```

Is this what you want the bot to do? Your code is kinda absurd, mind explaining what you wanna achieve with that code?

If you're just trying to change your prefix all you have to do it
`const prefix = 'b?'`